# Inference using model with low goodness of fit.

Tags: inference, goodness-of-fit, partial-least-squares

Assuming a model is correctly specified, would it be appropriate to draw inferences based on a model with a low Goodness of Fit (~0.15)?

Of course, using such a model to make predictions is likely not a good idea. But if the coefficients happen to be significant, can we actually use them to draw inferences based on the dataset?

For some context, we are trying to use a PLS - SEM model to investigate the impact of various kinds of teaching methodology on classroom performance. We represented the presence (or absence) of a particular teaching method in class through the use of dummy variables.

If the path coefficients happen to be significant (very close to 0), can we use this as evidence that the various teaching methods somehow had some kind of an effect on performance? We are not looking to quantify the magnitude this effect (which is unrealistic, given the small sample size). Rather, we aim to show the existence of such an effect.

The low GOF is probably partly due to the small sample sizes, since we only have around 50 samples distributed among 4 groups to work with.

Comment: If linear model assumptions are more or less satisfied, then yes you can. Though if you're going to be making coefficient interpretation then you should probably report confidence intervals along with point estimates.